# Search multiple User-inputted Text fields in database.Example:-Textfields like Designation,Location,Qualification,Gender

Tags: php, mysql, database

User will input/output some fields and exclude some fields. We want php- SQL query so that it should search in database for only inputted textfield values and display output.

Comment: @bub..We have multiple text boxes to search data in database[Data is already in database] . Example-Text boxes such as-Name,Location,Age,Address, Postcode, Contact, Qualification, Experience, Designation etc. Suppose User want to search according to Name and location and designation , it should search only give refined result according to these 3 fields. I want such query in PHP. Am New to PHP

Comment: Well, what @bub is trying to say is that StackOverflow is not a free code website. We love to solve issues our fellows encounter, and thus build a knowledge base. To avoid it getting out of the way, the askers **MUST** show implication into their issue. Just saying "I want THAT, do it for me now" without even asking something will get you downvotes and flags. Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Kyll..Sorry for this post.  We have done query for single search. We are just trying to get some code views so that we can implement it. We are trying to search for multiple text boxes. In short we will try to post the main code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try like the following so this can help you from the search string

```
$query = array();

$query[] = empty($_POST['name']) ? : 'name='.$_POST['name'];
$query[] = empty($address) ? : 'address'.$_POST['address'];
$results = implode('AND', $query);
$test = "SELECT * FROM tableName where '".$results."'";
```

Comment: $query = array();

           $query[] = empty($_POST['keyword_s_dec']) ? : 'cand_desc='.$_POST['keyword_s_dec'];
           $query[] = empty($_POST['keyword_s_location']) ? : 'cand_location='.$_POST['keyword_s_location'];
           
           $results = implode('AND', $query);
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate where '".$results."'";

Comment: We are getting error -Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp\www\pages\candidate\viewcandidate.php on line 496